# Исключения в контроллере FileResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, исключения

У меня есть метод, который возвращает файл пользователю. Но во время выполнения метода возможно исключение. Что мне прописать в catch,чтобы в случае появления исключения, пользователю выводилось представление с информацией об ошибке? Или что-либо сделать, чтобы словить это исключение?

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult Decrypted(HttpPostedFileBase upload, string key)
{
    string fileName = GetUniqueFileName(upload.FileName);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(upload.InputStream);
    image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));

    string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagePath);
    string extractedText = SteganoHelper.extractText(bmp);


        var baseLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Text/");
        var fileNameRes = GetUniqueFileName("res.txt");
        var fileLocationRes = Path.Combine(baseLocation, fileNameRes);

    try
    {
        extractedText = Crypto.DecryptStringAES(extractedText, key) + Environment.NewLine;
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fileLocationRes, extractedText, Encoding.UTF8);
        var doc = new byte[0];
        doc = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileLocationRes);
        return File(doc, "application / octet - stream", "decrypted.txt");
    }
    catch
    {
      ?????
    }


}
```

Comment: Хмм.. вероятнее всего ожидается 'втыканя' в catch MessageBox, если надо известить о чем то пользователя. Или способ обновления текста в элементе который отвечает у вас за диалог с пользователем. Или просто вернуть null, и уже там вызывать Alert.

Comment: Вместо `FileResult` возвращать `ActionResult`. В `catch`, соответственно, можно вернуть любой подходящий результат (сделать редирект на страницу ошибки).